# Synchronize the order of multiple observables

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have multiple (2-10) hot observables, each fires one event in a given time window but not in order.

Lets say I have 3 subjects, and to illustrate it they fire in following arbitrary orders:

```
Subjects: sA, sB, sC

Order of time window 1:
  sB, then sA, then sC
Order of time window 2:
  sA, then sC, then sB
Order of time window 3:
  sA, then sB, then sC
etc.
```

So if I would do a merge I would get following stream: sB, sA, sC, sA, sC, sB, sA, sB, sC, etc.

Now, here's my question: I'd like to force the order of events within each time window.

```
1. sA
2. sB
3. sC
```

Which would result in following merged stream: sA, sB, sC, sA, sB, sC, sA, sB, sC, etc.

The window time itself is not known, but since each event fires exactly once in each window we can assume that once all subjects have fired the windows is closed and a new one is opened.

Any Ideas how to do this elegantly?

Extended question (not as important): the observables are independent of each other so i need to introduce a common static method where I can synchronize the order of each observable.

```
public static IObservable<T> SynchronizeOrder<T>(IObservable<T> source, int order)
{
  //return synchronized source
}
```

**Update**: Something that wasn't clear in my original question was that the observables can be of different event types (that's why I didn't use a specific event data type in my example) and consequently I do not want to merge the ordered observables. I want to have a mechanism where I can ensure that independent observables are being synchronized in their order.

```
myEventStream
 .ObserveOn(TaskFactory)
 .DoSomeExpensiveComputation()
 .Order(2) //doesn't have to be an extension method
 .Subscibe(computationResult=>
            sharedRessourceWhereOrderMatters.Update(computationResult))
```

Comment: What opens each window? You say that `sA` closes each window, but without knowing what opens it, you can't know how long to hold `sB` and `sC` for if they arrive first.

Comment: Good point, my question wasn't clear enough, updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want using observable joins:

```
    using System.Reactive;
    using System.Reactive.Subjects;
    using System.Reactive.Linq;

    var a = new Subject<int>();
    var b = new Subject<int>();
    var c = new Subject<int>();

    var test = 
        Observable.When(
            a.And(b).And(c).Then((a1, b1, c1) => new int[] { a1, b1, c1 })
        ).SelectMany(arr => arr.ToObservable());

    var sub = test.Subscribe(val => Console.Write("{0} ", val));

    a.OnNext(1);
    b.OnNext(2);
    c.OnNext(3);

    a.OnNext(1);
    c.OnNext(3);
    b.OnNext(2);

    c.OnNext(3);
    a.OnNext(1);
    b.OnNext(2);

    Console.ReadKey();
    sub.Dispose();
```

The output is:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Notice however that:

1. This doesn't provide an extension method that allows you to inject a particular observable in some order. You would need to build the plan up using `And` (which can be done piecemeal), and then eventually execute it. The 'build up' order will be the output order.
2. This doesn't look at the actual window creation. However, there's no reason that couldn't be injected into the observable chain somewhere.
3. This solution will fire *once* every time all three observables have a value. You may need to set it up and tear it down at the right points to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks that helped me thinking about the problem, although I've ended up using a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

yamens answer is great for observables with the same type that are in the same scope. In my case (extended question), the observables can be of a different type and the order can be synchronized at any point in the execution.

So here's my proposed simple solution:

```
private readonly object syncRoot = new object();
private int sourceCount;
private readonly SortedDictionary<int, Action> buffer = new SortedDictionary<int, Action>();

public IObservable<T> Order<T>(IObservable<T> source, int order)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
            sourceCount++;

        source.Synchronize(syncRoot).Subscribe(item =>
        {
            buffer[order] = () => observer.OnNext(item);
            if(buffer.Count == sourceCount)
            {
                foreach (var action in buffer.Values)
                    action();
                buffer.Clear();
            }
        }, observer.OnError, observer.OnCompleted);

        return () =>
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
                sourceCount--;
        };
    });
}//end order
```

Comment: I see what you mean re: syncing at different times, but here the type of the observable is the same. In the end, if you are merging observable streams you need a single unification type at the end, and my answer can provide that (use a different selection function in `Then` if needed). Your solution has the right idea, but will be brittle in any exception scenario (one observable fires more than once for example).

Comment: Yes true, I think I gave the wrong impression that merging in the end is a requirement, I only wanted to illustrate the resulting order. In my case I have multiple independent components (almost like plugins) that deal with the same data stream asynchronously, e.g., do some computations. They share a singleton or service where they can synchronize the order of the continuation of the observables after a certain point in the computation. I wanna do this mainly because in certain scenarios the components have a priority order but I want to leave it to the component developer.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. Best of luck.